# Do electroluminescent quantum dot displays suffer from "burn-in" effect like OLED displays?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

To my knowledge, compared to oled, elqd displays will be very cheap to mass produce using ink jet printing process. Quantum dots can have very narrow FWHM which allows displays to have wider color gamut of >90% rec2020. The response times of quantum dots are also faster than oled. Most importantly, it is also self-emissive like OLED.

However, one of the biggest concerns I have is if it suffers the same "burn-in" effect like OLED. To my knowledge, the challenge of commercializing ELQD displays is that the lifetime of the blue emitter currently only lasts a couple of hours at 1000 nits. However, I'm not sure if the term "burn-in" is separate from "lifetime." In an OLED display, when a static logo is shown for a really long time without any "burn-in" compensation technologies, the logo will burn in and the respective pixels will permanently shift colors which is very noticeable. I wonder if the same occurs with ELQD displays. In addition, I have also read somewhere that quantum dots are also not truly inorganic materials because the "ligands" are organic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic.

Comment: @Mithoron Why do you say so? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Well, everything is based on or uses chemical compounds and materials, but it does not mean chemists are experts in everything involving matter. This is highly applied science.

Comment: @Poutnik Most people conducting research on Quantum Dots and in companies trying to use these in display applications have PhDs in Chemistry. If I cannot ask a question here, I don't think there is a more appropriate place to ask this question. I do not think a question should be classified as "off-topic" just because some users here are not familiar with the topic.

Comment: I do not say you cannot ask here, I just think meeting an expert in the area would be accidental.

Comment: This question enters the interface between chemistry (like how the material quantum dots are made of [partially/fully] converts into an other) and physics (HOMO/LUMO, DoS). Because the later offers a tag dedicated to [`quantum-dots`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-dots) and an *answered* [ELQD question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/720199/why-do-efficient-blue-emitters-leds-oleds-quantum-dots-take-much-longer-to-di) , I suggest to keep this interesting question open and to relay the question to sibling physics.se.

Comment: In order to make the question more answerable here, it might be worth adding something about the chemistry of quantum dot materials and how they differ from traditional OLEDs. The audience who know something about the chemistry will be larger than the audience with a good familiarity with the technology.

Comment: @matt_black I agreee, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot_display is a bit sparse, *chemically* speaking.